# Redirect URL with http but NOT 'localhost' value in app registration microsoft azure

Tags: azure-active-directory

When trying to access azure application using my local app it always give me an error saying `The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application`. I understood that the url(http://mylocalapp.val/options/msgraph365) in my localhost doesn't match on one of the redirect ulrs I registered on azure.

Azure only allows 'localhost' value if we are going to use http. Now, this is I am stuck with. I have configure in my apache and hosts file to use http://mylocalapp.val when ever I open my local app. The redirect url in my .env is and should always be 'http://mylocalapp.val/options/msgraph365' but the problem is I can't register this URL in azure since it is using http but the domain name is not `localhost`, its `mylocalapp.val`. I have seen to some applications with this kind of setup and it works but I don't know how they did it.

It there a setup that I missed in azure to enable this kind of setup? Or what should I register in my redirect url? I have already tried `http://localhost/options/msgraph365` and still no luck.

Answer (score 5):

> AADSTS50011 - The reply URL specified in the request does not match
> the reply URLs configured for the application

As you mentioned, this error usually occurs when there is a **mismatch** between the reply URLs defined in the Azure portal and the reply URL the application is providing to Azure AD.

Azure AD only accepts **saved reply URLs** which are already defined in Azure Portal. As you already know, Azure allows  `http`  protocol value for only **localhost**. Remaining all redirect URIs must begin with the scheme `https`. To use https, you should install **SSL certificate**.

- If you are using **localhost**, check if you have redirect URI something like this -> **`http://localhost: portNumber/options/msgraph365`** for deployed azure web app.
- If not, try to change the reply URL type in manifest so that you can make use of **https** for which you need **SSL certificate**. Then change your redirect URI to something like this: **`https://mylocalapp.val/options/msgraph365`**

To change the reply URL in **manifest**, go through the steps below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure AD -> App Registrations -> Your App -> Select Manifest (Under Manage)***

[image: 1]

For more information, go through the references below if they are helpful.

**Reference:**

[Redirect URI (reply URL) restrictions - Microsoft identity platform | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url#:%7E:text=%20In%20this%20approach:%20%201%20Create%20a,state%20parameter%20back%20to%20the%20application.%20More)

[Understanding the Azure Active Directory app manifest - Microsoft identity platform | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#replyurlswithtype-attribute)

Comment: hi @SrideviMachavarapu-MT, thank you for the response. your answer was very detailed, clean, and easy to understand. However, still even in the replyUrlsWithType it doesn't allow `http:mylocalapp.val/options/msgraph365`. it seems that manifest is just the object equivalent of all the config we set up in UI. - Still It won't allow me to save http that is NOT localhost value.
as an alternative, I changed my .env variable to `http://localhost/options/msgraph365` and then configure my apache server to redirect 'localhost' to 'http:mylocalapp.val'.

Comment: It's not possible to use **http** with your URL as it is not **localhost**. This is one of the redirect URIs **restriction** kept by Azure and please note that no other alternatives work. So, I suggested you to install SSL certificate to make use of ***https*** and change it in the manifest !