# Azure Web App created at localhost but not working

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I created web app in my Azure account. I have all details like tenat id, client id, client secret etc. While creating I have added uri as https://localhost and I also added scope Data.Read and added Application ID URI. But I can't open above mentioned url. Most possible that I am missing something in my mind and dont fully understand the rule how it should work, that is why I am asking for help. I need this localhost in order to test auth with Azure tokens. What exactly I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Azure allows `http` protocol value for only **localhost**. Remaining all redirect URIs must begin with the scheme `https`. To use https, you should install **SSL certificate**.

> **HTTP**: The HTTP scheme (`http://`) is supported  *only*  for  *localhost*  URIs and should be used only during active local application development and testing.

I am not sure what error you are getting Azure active directory basically Redirect back to the Redirect URL specified in the request provided to AAD after login using either the /authorize or /token endpoint is what AAD does. If the match is successful, AAD publishes the success response back to the same Redirect URI after successfully authenticating the user. Once the request reaches AAD, it verifies the Redirect URI and compares it with the reply URLs listed in the app registration.

For more information in detail, please **refer** below links:

[How to create Azure Web App | Ciemasen](https://ciemasen.com/articles/how-to-create-azure-webapp)

[Localhost exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url#localhost-exceptions)

[Redirect URL with http but NOT localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71350361/redirect-url-with-http-but-not-localhost-value-in-app-registration-microsoft-a)